# Getting Credentials File in the boto.cfg for Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm using AWS for the first time and have just installed boto for python.  I'm stuck at the step where it advices to:

"You can place this file either at /etc/boto.cfg for system-wide use or in the home directory of the user executing the commands as ~/.boto."

Honestly, I have no idea what to do.  First, I can't find the boto.cfg and second I'm not sure which command to execute for the second option.

Also, when I deploy the application to my server, I'm assuming I need to do the same thing there too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "You can place this file either at /etc/boto.cfg for system-wide use
>   or in the home directory of the user executing the commands as
>   ~/.boto."

The former simply means that you might create a configuration file named `boto.cfg` within directory `/etc` (i.e. it won't necessarily be there already, depending on how [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/) has been installed on your particular system).

The latter is indeed phrased a bit unfortunate - `~/.boto` means that boto will look for a configuration file named `.boto` within the home directory of the user executing the commands (i.e. Python scripts) which are facilitating the boto library.

You can read more about this in the boto wiki article [BotoConfig](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html), e.g. regarding the question at hand:

> A boto config file is simply a .ini format configuration file that
>   specifies values for options that control the behavior of the boto
>   library. Upon startup, the boto library looks for configuration files
>   in the following locations and in the following order:
>
> 1. /etc/boto.cfg - for site-wide settings that all users on this machine
>      will use
> 2. ~/.boto - for user-specific settings

You'll indeed need to prepare a respective configuration file on the server your application is deployed to as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

For those who want to configure the credentials in Windows:

1-Create your file with the name you want(e.g boto_config.cfg) and place it in a location of your choice(e.g C:\Users\\configs).

2- Create an environment variable with the Name='BOTO_CONFIG' and Value= file_location/file_name

3- Boto is now ready to work with credentials automatically configured!

- To create environment variables in Windows follow this tutorial: http://www.onlinehowto.net/Tutorials/Windows-7/Creating-System-Environment-Variables-in-Windows-7/1705

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking for information on the now-current `boto3`, it does not use a separate configuration file but rather respects the default one created by the aws cli when running `aws configure` (Ie, it will look at `~/.aws/config`)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21345540/3345375 for Boto version 2.29.0 and up.