# Recommended way to manage credentials with multiple AWS accounts?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

What is the best way to manage multiple Amazon Web Services (AWS) accounts through `boto`?

I am familiar with [BotoConfig](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) files, which I'm using. But each file describes only a single account...and I am working with more than just the one organization. For all the usual legal, financial, and security reasons, those accounts cannot be commingled.

Currently I am using one `boto` config file per account. E.g.:

- `~/.boto` default account
- `~/.boto_clowncollege` for "clowncollege" account
- `~/.boto_razorassoc` for "razorassoc" account
- `~/.boto_xyz` for "xyz" account

Then something like:

```
def boto_config_path(account=None):
    """
    Given an account name, return the path to the corresponding boto
    configuration file. If no account given, return the default config file.
    """
    path = '~/.boto' + ('_' + account if account else '')
    clean_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
    if os.path.isfile(clean_path):
        return clean_path
    else:
        errmsg = "cannot find boto config file {} for {}".format(clean_path, account)
        raise ValueError(errmsg)

def aws_credentials(account=None):
    """
    Return a tuple of AWS credentials (access key id and secret access key) for
    the given account.
    """
    try:
        cfg = INIConfig(open(boto_config_path(account)))
        return ( cfg.Credentials.aws_access_key_id, cfg.Credentials.aws_secret_access_key )
    except Exception:
        raise

conn = EC2Connection(*aws_credentials('razorassoc'))
```

Good, bad, or indifferent? Suggested improvements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the future, boto will provide better tools to help you manage multiple credentials but at the moment, there are a couple of environment variables that might help out.

First, you can set BOTO_CONFIG to point to a boto config file that you want to use and it will override any config file found in the normal locations.

Secondly, you can set BOTO_PATH to a colon-separated list of places to look for a boto config file and it will search there first, prior to the normal search locations.

Neither of those give you exactly what you want but it may make it easier to accomplish with a bit less code.

If you have ideas about how you would like this to work in boto, please let me know!

Comment: `BOTO_CONFIG` is indeed very easy to use. But changing a external shell/system environment setting from within a program to communicate with a module seems circumnavigational. Somewhat inelegant for programs (e.g. monitoring apps) that want to connect to multiple accounts simultaneously. Potentially also unsafe; Python docs for `os.environ` warn '**Note** On some platforms, including FreeBSD and Mac OS X, setting environ may cause memory leaks.'

Comment: BTW, the [Boto Config Tutorial](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) does not mention `BOTO_CONFIG` or `BOTO_PATH`. I didn't know about either until your answer above.

Comment: What I would like: A `boto.connect()` method called something like `boto.connect('ec2', config_path='~/.boto_clowncollege')`. That would unify the ~25 `boto.connect_xyx` rifle-shots and give a simple, all-Python way to integrate the use of multiple config files.

Comment: How about a way to have different "profiles" defined in your boto config file and then refer to those profiles by name, e.g. boto.connect_ec2(profile='clowncollege') or something like that?

Comment: I like native named profiles, but I think I'd prefer separate files. BotoConfig already uses INI sections (Credentials and Boto); AFAIK there's no INI mechanism to provide another layer to make those sections specific to given profiles. So it'd take a format change (JSON or YAML?) Even so, you might not want to glom all the *privileged* profile information for multiple accounts into a single file. Finally, operating at scale, you might want profile info coming from a database text/blob field. IMO, multiple profiles in one config file is contrary to how one would operate with many profiles.

Comment: I think it's the future now. The accepted answer ought to be changed.

Answer (score 73):

**updated 2015-02-06, corrected 2015-03-19** by following top section

## New standardized sharing of boto and AWSCLI credentials (boto>==2.29.0)

Since boto 2.29 there is new easy way for sharing BOTO and AWS CLI credentials as described by Mike
Garnaat in [A New and Standardized Way to Manage Credentials in the AWS
SDKs](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs)

The aim is to:

1. allow sharing credentials by boto, AWSCLI and possibly other SDKs
2. keep all configuration in single file, located in user profile directory
3. allow using named profiles
4. keep it as simple as possible (e.g. prevent conflicts with other methods)

### Create credentials file

Create the file `~/.aws/credentials` (Mac/Linux) or `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` (Windwos) as
follows:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr
region = eu-west-1

[jekyl]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr
region = eu-west-1

[hyde]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxZ
aws_secret_access_key = CxxxZ
region = eu-west-1
```

From now on, you may use a code like this:

#### Use default profile

```
import boto
con = boto.connect_s3()
```

#### Use explicit profile set by `AWS_PROFILE` env. var

(this is my favourite option keeping profile name out of code and still giving the deployer of my application a chance to pick specific profile)

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=jekyl
```

and keep your code as simple as before:

```
import boto
con = boto.connect_s3()
```

#### Specify explicit profile in your code

```
import boto
con = boto.connect_s3(profile_name="jekyl")
```

**This is all you typically need to do**

The logic for picking proper credentials is described in [boto issue #2292](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2292) as follows:

> The loading order from highest to lowest precedence:
>
> 1.Directly passed from code
>
> 2. Environment variables for key/secret
> 3. Environment variables for profile
> 4. Shared credential file explicit profile
> 5. Shared credential file default profile
> 6. Config file explicit profile
> 7. Config file Credentials section
>
> A profile passed from code overrides any set in an environment variable.

To keep things clean and simple, it is good to get rid of older methods, so remove any old style files (like `~/.aws/config` or `~/.boto`), unset environmental varialbe `BOTO_CONFIG` if set and
possibly also the file, to which such variable points to.

**And that is really all for boto >=2.29.0**

Note: Do not attempt to control location of config file by env.variable (like `AWS_CONFIG_FILE`), it does not work as expected.

## Use boto config profile (boto>=2.24.0)

**Following description is kept here only for those, who cannot upgrade to boto 2.29.0 or higher**

Since boto 2.24.0 there is a feature called `profile_name`

In your `~/.boto` file you already have your [Credentials] section, this will serve as fallback option, and then [profile ] sections serving for different profiles:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr

[profile jekyl]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr

[profile hyde]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxZ
aws_secret_access_key = CxxxZ
```

Then, when creating connection, you use this way:

```
import boto
con = boto.connect_s3(profile_name="jekyl")
```

Note, that this feature is available since boto 2.24.0.

Tutorial is here http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html?highlight=profile

There are even some notes about using keyrings, but I will first get used to this profile stuff, which I was dreaming of few years.

### Sharing config file with AWSCLI

AWSCLI became really great tool. As format of config file is almost the same, I use it in following way:

1. keep `~/.aws/config` file as created by AWSCLI (this is default location)
2. copy section `[default]` and rename it to `[Credentials]` (leaving the same values inside).
3. add whatever profiles I use
4. set `BOTO_CONFIG` variable to point to this `~/.aws/config` file.

The `~/.boto` would then become `~/.aws/config with following content:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr

[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr

[profile jekyl]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxA
aws_secret_access_key = Zxxxr

[profile hyde]
aws_access_key_id = AxxxZ
aws_secret_access_key = CxxxZ
```

This way, it gets shared for both AWSCLI and boto including profiles.

Comment: Boto 2.33.0, this doesn't work. 1)Already have ~/.aws/config  2)Copied [default] to [Credentials] 3)Added new [profile MyUser] section with new credentials 4)Called boto.sqs_connect().  I get boto.provider.ProfileNotFoundError: Profile "MyUser" not found!

Comment: @Cory I checked it on my machine (upgrading to the latest boto 2.33.0). Following exactly the steps above from my answer and then following your steps, all went OK and I was able to create SQS connection. Few things to check: Do not edit `credentials` instead of `config` file, they may live in the same directory, but have different format for defining profiles - `credentials` file does not use prefix `profile ` for profile sections.

Comment: I don't know in which version the AWS CLI team introduced this, but at least as of AWS CLI 1.5.2, ~/.aws/credentials is now read (preferentially) for profile information, in addition to ~/.aws/config. See [the AWS CLI configuration docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) for more information.

Comment: @Cory Description updated to reflect latest simplified method for sharing credentials between AWSCLI, boto and other SKDs - shall work for boto >==2.29.0.

Comment: @gotgenes - shared config for boto >==2.29.0 added. It coversl latest AWS CLI too.

Comment: From where did you take `[profile jekyl]` and `[profile hyde]` and `[jekyl]` and `[hyde]`? And who is `[default]`?

Comment: @green See [A New and Standardized Way to Manage Credentials in the AWS SDKs](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs) - my `jekyl` and `hyde` are `Alice` and `Bob` there. Use AWS IAM to create credential for the users/profiles you need.

Comment: what about when you have cross account enabled? I don't have the "credentials" of all of our customer accounts but an account across all the customers. So my file credentails just have our main key password for our main account and in the config I have the rest of the profiles like:[profile asv_1] role_arn= arn:aws:iam:xxxxx....... with this scenario could work your solution?

Comment: Is it safe to add credentials in these config files because these file are in readable format? Anyone can access the credentials of others if it is a shared machine.
Is it not good to encrypt these and store in a DB and access when required? we can use it as described in below link.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#method-parameters

Comment: @dj1986 one has to prevent others to access your configuration data. This is best done on user profile level, then you can keep configuration simple. Trying to encrypt particular configuration file is only adding extra step without solution. Someone will have to provide information to decrypt the configuration file anyway. Solve the problem on appropriate level (user profile) or consider your (shared) system broken from security point of view.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than creating a bunch of separate boto config files, consider using the ConfigParser module and creating a section in the .boto file for each of your accounts.

your .boto file might look something like this

```
#Contents of ~/.boto
[clown-college]
aws_access_key_id = 123sesamestreet
aws_secret_access_key = 678idsaf567ujd
[razor-assoc]
aws_access_key_id = 437piedmont
aws_secret_access_key = 997567ujdfs
```

In your python code, use ConfigParser to load the appropriate access key for the account you wish to use.

```
import ConfigParser
from os.path import expanduser

########## BEGIN MAIN ##############

# get the path to the user's homedir
user_home = expanduser("~")

#load their .boto config file
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read([str(user_home + "/.boto")])

#get the keypair for ClownCollege
print config.get('clown-college', 'aws_access_key_id')
print config.get('clown-college', 'aws_secret_access_key')

print config.get('razor-assoc', 'aws_access_key_id')
print config.get('razor-assoc', 'aws_secret_access_key')
```

This can be wrapped in a function to use across your boto code to easily set the correct account.

Comment: From where did you take `[razor-assoc]` and `[clown-college]`?

Answer (score 1):

As of boto >= 2.38, it seems like all previous solutions can cause immense headaches and problems.

After testing this extensively today on multiple BSD based platforms, it appears that the most effective way **now** to manage the different profile authentications for AWSCLI and py-boto is to use the `aws configure` interactive script. Call it without a profile, and it will fill out a [default] block for both the .aws/config and .aws/credentials files, and in addition it will configure whatever other magic it needs to get boto working with your aws toolset (although it's unclear yet just what hexes it's casting on your localhost). Call it again with any profile name, and it will create an appropriate entry.

Note that this still doesn't work for versions of boto < 2.3.

```
aws configure --profile somename
AWS Access Key ID [None]: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that per http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html -- when using **connect_cloudwatch()** for boto version 2.48.0 I actually needed to provide the

**cloudwatch_region_endpoint**

Or the connection still would use the same region as the current instance, when pushing data **from the instance itself** in EC2 (when the instance is in a different region as where it's pushing to).

```
cat .boto
[Boto]
cloudwatch_region_name = us-west-2
cloudwatch_region_endpoint = monitoring.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

I tried adding that to the .aws/credentials profile, but it didn't seem to work.

```
cat .aws/credentials 
[cloudwatch_centralized_reporting]
region = us-west-2
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXX
```