# How do I sync values in setup.py / install_requires with Pipfile / packages

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

If you work on a project that uses both `setup.py` and `Pipfile` you often find the same values in: `Pipfile/[packages]` and `setup.py/install_requires`.

Does anyone know how I can tell `Pipfile` to use values from `setup.py/install_requires` for `[packages]`?

Answer (score 7):

Within your `setup.py`:

1. Define a function to read a section:

   ```
   def locked_requirements(section):
   """Look through the 'Pipfile.lock' to fetch requirements by section."""
       with open('Pipfile.lock') as pip_file:
           pipfile_json = json.load(pip_file)

       if section not in pipfile_json:
           print("{0} section missing from Pipfile.lock".format(section))
           return []

       return [package + detail.get('version', "")
               for package, detail in pipfile_json[section].items()]
   ```
2. Within the `setup` function return the list from the `default` section:

   ```
   setup(
       # ...snip...
       install_requires=locked_requirements('default'),
       # ...snip...
   )
   ```

***IMPORTANT NOTE***: include `Pipfile.lock` within the `MANIFEST.in` like:

```
include Pipfile.lock
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. One question: why should we include a `MANIFEST.in`? We tried without it and `Pipfile.lock` still is shipped in the Python wheel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727709/do-python-projects-need-a-manifest-in-and-what-should-be-in-it https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html

Comment: Why we should use Pipfile.lock? I was inspired by your answer but my function in setup.py reads only [packages] section from Pipfile (and ignore [dev-packages]). It skips packages which are not needed for runtime. Is there some drawback which I do not see now?

Comment: The `Pipfile.lock` will not drift with updated packages, using the `Pipfile` may have breaking results due to downstream dependencies or breaking version changes.