# does python wheel remove yml files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, yaml, python-wheel

This is part of my docker file:

```
RUN python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
RUN find dist -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.tar.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} athena.tar.gz

FROM python:3.7.4-slim
```

after I build my docker file. I run my container bash and type

```
find . -type f -name "*.yml"
```

the result is empty.

I have lots of yml files in my project.
My code run correctly out of container but in docker I get errors which say couldn't find my yml files.

Does wheel remove yml files?(maybe does it think they are useless?)

Comment: Please include the contents of your `setup.py`.

Comment: it does not, unless your setup.py deletes them as a side-effect

Comment: your dockerfile also looks out of order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wheels won't generally include anything but Python files unless you've specified a manifest.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24727824/51685) for more details, but the tl;dr is that [a `MANIFEST.in` file](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) next to your `setup.py` with

```
recursive-include *.yml
```

should include all YAML files.

Comment: the question as written is not about the contents of the wheel