# Manifest.in seems to be ignored

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

So I have a package as follows:

```
Dir
+---src
|   +---Package
|       +---__init__.py
|       +---Certs
|           +---SomeCertificate
|
+---setup.py
+---MANIFEST.in
```

my setup.py looks like this:

```
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setuptools.setup(
    name = 'myPackage',
    install_requires=required,
    package_dir = {
            '': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe = False
)
```

and my MANIFEST.in looks like this:

```
recursive-include *
```

I want all folders, structure, and files in Package to be included when I do `pip install myPackage` but MANIFEST.in seems to be ignored - the Certs folder and its contents are not in the installed package's site-packages folder. Been looking through documentation but still can't work out what I'm doing wrong - anyone know?

Comment: "but MANIFEST.in seems to be ignored" What is your evidence for this? What happens when you run the command, and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727709/do-python-projects-need-a-manifest-in-and-what-should-be-in-it help?

Comment: No, I still can't get it to work, I just tried to do package_data={'myPackage:['*']} which did include files directly under myPackage folder into the site-package folder, but does not recursively find all folders and files

Comment: Maybe `recursive-include src *`. As far as I know `recursive-include` requires 2 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
# https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/
graft src/Package
global-exclude __pycache__
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

> **graft dir-pattern** Add all files under directories matching dir-pattern