# Boto Exception NoAuthHandler Found

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/database.py", line 21, in <module>
    import dynamoStorage
File "/Users/tai/Desktop/FlashY/flashy/sniffer/dynamoStorage.py", line 37, in <module>
    swfTable = Table(decompiled_dynamo_table, connection=dynamoConn)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.connection = DynamoDBConnection()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 183, in __init__
    super(DynamoDBConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1073, in __init__
    profile_name=profile_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 572, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 883, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials
```

When I had the auth directly in the file my keys worked so I know the keys are correct.

I have for awsAccess.py:

```
#aswAccess holds the names of the bash environment set keys.
#used by other classes to create a connection to aws
aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY');
aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY');
aws_dynamo_region=os.getenv('DYANAMO_REGION')
```

and I have for database.py

```
#for connecting to aws
aws_access_key_id=awsAccess.aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key=awsAccess.aws_secret_access_key
aws_dynamo_region=awsAccess.aws_dynamo_region

aws_dynamo_table="decompiled_swf_text"
conn= S3Connection(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key);
dynamoConn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
dTable = dynamoConn.get_table(aws_dynamo_table)
```

So I know the keys themselves are correct.

I have a .bash_profile file that looks like this (**indicating removed, also I tried with and without ""'s):

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY="myAccessKey**"

export AWS_SECRET_KEY="mySecretKey**"

export DYNAMO_REGION="us-east"
```

I run source ~/.bash_profile, and then tried running but get the error. I can't see why importing would alter the impact of the same key string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few tips:

- assert in your code, that the values for ID aws_access_key and aws_secret_access_key are not empty. It is likely, you do not have them set at the place you think you have.
- remove authentication arguments from `boto.connect_<something>`. This will let `boto` to use built in authentication handlers and these shall try reading the file, checking environmental variables etc. You will have your code simpler while still being able to provide all what is needed by any of `boto` authentication methods.
- my favourit authentication method is to use ini file (usually named `boto.cfg`) and having `BOTO_CONFIG` environmental variable set to full path to this file, e.g. to `"/home/javl/.boto/boto.cfg"
- note, that if you pass any of the authentication parameters to `boto.connect_<something>` with value `null`, it will work as `boto` will check other methods to find the value.
- since about a year ago, there is an option `profile`, allowing to refer to specific profile in boto config file. This let me switching to different profiles anywhere in the code.

For more tips and details, see [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21345540/346478)

Comment: Hm interesting. I added assert statements just to check and realized that aws_dynamo_region is None... hmm thanks for the link. Can you explain what you mean by remove authentication arguments from boto.connect_<something> as in boto.connect(..)?

Comment: @TaiHirabayashi By removing I mean changing `dynamoConn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)` to 
`dynamoConn = boto.connect_dynamodb()`. 
This shall give `boto` good chance to try it's best to read credentials from config file or from
environmental variables. This way my code get much simpler (a lot of credentials handling got
removed) and all is resolved at the time of starting by `BOTO_CONFIG` env variable, variables for
key and access key or these globally available methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had Problem with Ubuntu Wily (15.10).

Here there is an update for ConfigParser.

`.get` has a additional Parameter, but that are not supported with boto.pyami.config.

see [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3370) and [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue21159)