# AWS boto SQS connection not support profile_name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I have a credentials file with multiple profiles.  In my script, the profile name is passed as an argument and all of the connect_xxx calls use that profile name.  This has been working fine - until I tried to connect to SQS.  When I attempt to connect to SQS, i get: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile_name'.

For example, the code below works fine - until the SQS connect.  Am I missing something, or did AWS forget to implement profile_name on SQS connect?

```
region_name = 'us-east-1'
profile_name = 'my-valid'
iam_conn = boto.connect_iam(profile_name=profile_name)
s3_conn = boto.connect_s3(profile_name=profile_name)
ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region( region_name, profile_name=profile_name )
vpc_conn = boto.vpc.connect_to_region( region_name, profile_name=profile_name )
sqs_conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region( region_name, profile_name=profile_name )
```

Comment: I just tried it with version 2.36.0 and it works.  Perhaps you could try updating?

Answer (score 0):

Boto has the ability to read credentials from either the AWS Metadata (used when an Amazon EC2 instance is launched with a role), or from a local credentials file.

There's good examples here:

- [Recommended way to manage credentials with multiple AWS accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286479/recommended-way-to-manage-credentials-with-multiple-aws-accounts)

It looks like it requires the credentials in a `.boto` file rather than some of the other filenames that credentials are often passed.

Make sure you have the latest version of boto. On Linux, do: `sudo pip install boto --upgrade`