# Boto.conf not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am running a flask app on an AWS EC2 server, and have been using boto to access data stored in dynamoDB. After accidentally adding `boto.conf` to a git commit (and push and pull on the server), I have found that my python code can no longer locate the boto.conf file. I rolled back the changes with git, but the problem remains.

The python module and boto.conf file exist in the same directory, but when the module calls

```
boto.config.load_credential_file('boto.conf')
```

I get the `flask` error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'boto.conf'`.

Comment: Did you try the full path for your `boto.conf` file ?

Comment: Could it be a permission issue ? What are the permissions for `boto.conf`?

Comment: i tried various permissions using chmod; i tried 600, 400, etc.

Comment: You can try 666 or 777

Answer (score 0):

As per [Documentation](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html):

I'm not really sure why you are using `boto.config_load_credential_file`. In general you can pick up the config in a file called either `~/.boto` or `/etc/boto.cfg`.

You can also look at this questions from SO that also answers how to get the configuration for boto: [Getting Credentials File in the boto.cfg for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197385/getting-credentials-file-in-the-boto-cfg-for-python)

Comment: I'm trying to load the credentials so that I can call the boto feature Table several times later in the file, which is why I chose to load the file in directly.

Comment: You don't have to grab the credentials out of the config file yourself.  Just have the config file in one of the two locations described above (or set BOTO_CONFIG to point to it) and boto will find the credentials and use them.